# Switching between app views on Android

Tags: android

I have a button created on my main (activity) using . I set an onClick() method to determine the actions of the button. I want to display another view on clicking the button. The android:onclick("") call uses a string parameter. How can i reference the other view? I have its xml activity and content files built and the java file is properly put together and tested on my sdk to be working. But, how should i call the new object's view? I tried calling getApplication() but it crashes the app.
I'll appreciate any assistance.

Here is what i tried:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AppActivity app = new AppActivity();
    getApplicationContext().stopService(new Intent());
    app.getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent());
}
```

Comment: You need to post your relevant code.

Comment: @wvdz, I edited the post to include the how I set the onClick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change activities use this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AvitivityName.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

If you just want to change **views**, use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.myXML);
```

in your `onCreate`.

If you want to pass data between activities, use `putExtra` and `getExtra`:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,SendMessage.class);
i.putExtra("Hi", user.getUserAccountId()+"");
context.startActivity(i);
```

and to get:

```
Intent i= getIntent();
i.getExtra("Hi");
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Worked quite well. You guys are too skilled, I duff my hat!

Comment: @aburimegregory Hey, if it worked, please press on the check mark under the like buttons. That way, you can _accept_ my answer. Glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You have to save your current Activity `context` somewhere and then use it to call the new activity:

```
private Context ctx;
public Class CurrentActivity extends Activity{
    // let's save it in your onCreate method
    onCreate(Bundle savedBundleState){
       ctx = this;
    } 

    // now on your onClick method
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Toast.makeText(ctx, "I'm clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AppActivity.class);
      ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Refaat. I did exactly this and it stil crashed. I will try to implement it as contentViews and see what I get.

Comment: if its crashing you 'd better add your stacktrace to the question so that it will be easy for us to help you

Comment: Thanks, Refaat. I'm grateful.